# How to filter records with specific time duration

Tags: formula, formula-field

Our organization time zone is pst. And user timezone is also pst. So, I need the records created between 4:31 PM pst to 4:29 AM pst.

I tried to create a formula field like this. And it's showing hours now  But I am unable to figure out how to setup minutes & filter only records created under this duration

My Formula:

> VALUE(MID (TEXT (CreatedDate -7/24),12,2))

Comment: Can you give us more detail? If you're trying to run a SoQL, why create a formula field? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: No, I'm trying to do it from standard reporting. So, I am trying to create formula field in sfdc any possibility?

Answer (score -1):

You can use a Formula Date/Time field with this formula:

```
CreatedDate - ((NUM_OF_HOURS * 60)/1440)
```

Comment: Could you please explain the formula & specifically Num_of_hours in the sense

Comment: In your formula you tried to subtract 7 hours from the createddate field:
You have to create a formula Date/Time Field and not a text.

You can use this formula too:
CreatedDate - (7/24)

you can reduce the 60/1440 = 24, which is the number of hours a day.

Comment: Here is a link:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000221466&type=1

Comment: My formula is working perfectly with hours because i'm subtracting users timezone only.But the problem with minutes here

Comment: As I said, try to use a Date/Time field instead of Text

Comment: Then what about minutes?

Comment: You can add or subtract the minutes like this:
CreatedDate - (((NUM_OF_HOURS * 60) - NUM_OF_MINUTES )/1440)

Comment: Will you please explain your answer a bit briefly in the answer section.

Comment: A Day has 1440 minutes (24 hours * 60 minutes)
So all what i'm doing, is adding/subtracting a number of mintues from a day

Example: 
CreatedDate - (((7 * 60) - 25)/1440)
In this Example I'm substracting 7 hours and 25 minutes from the createddate field

If we say that CreatedDate = 2018.11.02 18:00:00
Then using the example this will come --> 2018.11.02 10:35:00